# Выравнивание содержимого в блоке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть несколько блоков `div` с `display:inline-block;` в них по картинке.

Так как `height` у изображений разный хочу выровнять их но центру нижнего края.

Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `display: flex`:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 5px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" style="height: 20px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 120px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 50px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 12px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 42px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 123px"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height: 95px"></div>
</div>
```